# Match string between ; and %

Tags: r, regex

I wish to extract the decimal value in the string without the % sign. So in this case, I want the numeric 0.45

```
x <- "document.write(GIC_annual[\"12-17 MTH\"][\"99999.99\"]);0.450%"
str_extract(x, "^;[0-9.]")
```

My attempt fails. Here's my thinking.

- Begin the extraction at the semicolon ^;
- Grab any numbers between 0 and 9.
- Include the decimal point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have this option:

```
stringr::str_extract(y, "\\d\\.\\d{1,}(?=%)")
[1] "0.450"
```

So basically you look ahead and check if there is `%` or not, if yes, you capture the digits before it.

**Details**

`\\d` digit;

`\\.` dot;

`\\d` digit;

`{1,}` capturing 1 or more digit after `.`;

`(?=%)` look ahead and check if there is `%` and if there is one, it retuns captured number

Comment: So it searches for a % sign - (?=%). If it finds one, then it looks before the % sign for a digit followed by a decimal and then any number of digits. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly, if  (?=%) is true, then it goes back and finds the pattern you want

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want semi-colon in the output use it as lookbehind regex.

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=;)[0-9]\\.[0-9]+")
#[1] "0.450"
```

In base R using `sub` :

```
sub('.*;([0-9]\\.[0-9]+).*', '\\1', x)
```